# High chart exporting button doesn't show up if series updated later

Tags: javascript, webpack, highcharts

The problem is that the Highcharts exporting button doesn't show up if the data is updated later on to another function. However, if charts being initialized with data inside the  `get.JSON` call back it does show up. Here's my webpack snippet:

```
require('expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery!jquery');

function main(analytics, Highcharts) {
  'use strict';
    var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'employee-trend',
          type: 'line',
          zoomType: 'x',
                spacingRight: 20,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Trend'
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          labels: {
            format: '{value:%e. %b %Y}'
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Series'
          }
        },
          tooltip: {
            xDateFormat: "%A, %b %e %Y"
        }
      });
      chart.showLoading();
    jQuery.getJSON(location.href+'/getdata', function (data) {
          var series = {
                name: 'Series',
                tooltip: {valueDecimals:0},
                data: data.reverse()
            };
        chart.hideLoading();
        chart.renderer.image('/static/images/logo-grayscale-transparent.png', 261, 171, 185, 31).add();
        chart.addSeries(series);
        console.log(data);
    });
}

require(['../js/analytics', '../vendor/highcharts/highcharts.src.js', '../vendor/highcharts/exporting'], main)
```

Comment: Hi @Omar, Which Highcharts version did you use? I have tried to reproduce the issue, but here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/40xtcqbe/ everything works as expected.

Comment: The version was 5, because of the webpack loading it couldn't find the exporting. using `window.onload` seems to have solved it.